# How to make superscripts inside glue?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I would like to be able to make superscripts inside a `glue()` function:

```
   glue::glue("{seq(0, 1500, by = 250)} μg/m^3")
```

In this way the m^3 is not evaluated, so I tried to do something like this:

```
   glue::glue("{seq(0, 1500, by = 250)} μg/{expression(m^3)}")
```

What I want to do with it, is to use it as the `label` argument in a `scale_x_continuous()` function in ggplot2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your end goal is to format something in `{ggplot2}` you can use the [{ggtext}](https://github.com/wilkelab/ggtext) package to apply markdown formatting to your labels:

```r
library(tibble)
library(ggplot2)

your_sequence <- seq(0, 1500, by = 250)

labels <- glue::glue("{your_sequence} μg/m^3")

data <- tibble(x = your_sequence,
               y = sample(100:120, 7),
               labels = labels)

ggplot(data, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = your_sequence, labels = labels) +
  theme(axis.text.x = ggtext::element_markdown())
```

The trick is in applying `ggtext::element_markdown()` to the `axis.text.x` parameter of your `theme()`.

Doing it this way you also don't need to add the expression inside your `glue::glue()` code.

I hope this helps!

Comment: For anyone else out there looking for a way to put superscript or subscript inside glue, outside of ggplot, you can create an object containing the superscript font and pass that to glue. i.e. `super <- "m^3^"; glue("{seq(0, 1500, by = 250)} μg/{super}")`. I'll also note that depending on how you are rendering the output, you may need to use "^3^" not "^3" to get the superscript.

Comment: Or if you are looking for a way to put super or subscript inside a glue object within geom_text, this solution works: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55264215/9154433